# Is there mineral nitrogen on Martian surface?

Tags: mars, planetary-resources

I am aware of the atmospheric composition and pressure. I am looking for research papers which state the mineral content of Martian soil.

Comment: Related possible duplicate [Would a settlement on Mars need to import Nitrogen?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/3363/109)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Would a settlement on Mars need to import Nitrogen?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/3363/would-a-settlement-on-mars-need-to-import-nitrogen)

Comment: This is a good question. Right now it's on hold for being off-topic but if you look at the possible duplicates I think it's possible you were asking about nitrogen for a specific reason *that really was related to space exploration*. The problem is that you didn't say that explicitly. The more you can explain about what it is you are looking for and in this case, *especially why*, the better a question can be answered. You are welcome to modify the question and explain further, maybe you are interested in something else instead?

Comment: One could argue that there is a space exploration component to this question, since the given answer involves experimentation on soil proved to be Martian.  Which did require standardizing it against Mars itself.

Answer (score 4):

According to [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/content/goddard/mars-nitrogen) the answer is "Yes".  Nitric oxide, which can be formed from pyrolysis of nitrates, evolved from heated samples of Martian soil.

Nitrates on Earth may be made by biological processes, but also by nonbioligical processes such as lightning.  The NASA report gives no indication that the Martian nitrates are of biological origin.